# Using IF in AJAX Result

Tags: javascript, ajax

In my form i am checking if there is same value in database or not when form submitted. The code below works fine and is giving the rigth result of AJAX post but the problem is when giving alert according to the wrong result, javascript alert and focus works but form still submits after these.

Button for submit:

```
<input type="submit" name="kaydet" class="btn btn-success form-control" 
onClick="return kaynak_kontrol()" value="Kaydet">
```

AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function kaynak_kontrol(){
  Form=document.forms['depo_kayit'];
  var depo_sube_no = document.getElementById('depo_sube_no').value; 
  var depo_firma_no = document.getElementById('depo_firma_no').value;
  var depo_kodu = document.getElementById('depo_kodu').value;
  var dataString ="depo_sube_no="+depo_sube_no+"&depo_firma_no="+depo_firma_no+"&depo_kodu="+depo_kodu; 

  $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "depo_kodu_kontrol.php", 
    data: dataString, 
    success: function(result){ 
      if(result != 0){
        alert("Aynı şubede aynı isimde iki depo olamaz!");
        document.getElementById('depo_kodu').focus();
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
        Form.submit();
      }
    }
  });
 }
 </script>
```

Can you help me why i return false is not working and form still submits?

Comment: Try adding a prevent default to the binding.  The default action for a submit button on a form is to submit the form so you have to explicitly prevent that.  https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: do it like @nurdyguy recommended or change `<input type="submit" name="kaydet" class="btn btn-success form-control" 
onClick="return kaynak_kontrol()" value="Kaydet">` to `<input type="button" name="kaydet" class="btn btn-success form-control" 
onClick="return kaynak_kontrol()" value="Kaydet">` - i changed "input" to "button"

Comment: Thanks you for replies. Added preventDefault and form submitting stopped on wrong result  BUT now right result is not submitting the  form.                                                                                         
     return true;
    Form.submit();

Comment: @Serter that's a different problem.

Comment: What can cause to this different problem?

Comment: Try `$('#_').submit()` replacing the '_' with the id from your form.

Comment: @nurdyguy why? `Form.submit()` is just fine, and would bypass any jquery bound submit events. The problem is here: `result != 0`

Comment: @nurdyguy sorry didn't submit the form :(

Comment: result != 0 is working fine. Cuase when the result == 0 form doesn't submit and alert windows comes and focuses on the input.

Comment: @Serter Sounds like you know where the problem is then.

Comment: Don't do field validation on submit, do it before

Comment: `else {  return true;  Form.submit();  }`  That won't work because you always return before you submit.

Comment: Shortly this is the point i can not understand, return false is working but return true; Form.submit(); is not working. Which changes should i do?

Answer (score 0):

you need to prevent the form submission manually using jQuery `event.preventDefault()`

here is a small fix

```
function kaynak_kontrol(event){ // notice the new parameter !
    event.preventDefault();
    //the rest of your code
```